# Numpy digitize error: object of too small depth for desired array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, valueerror

I have a masked array data, and I want to digitize to check the median data for each bins.
So I tried to use below codes

```
bin_num1 = 5

bins1 = np.linspace(min(np.log10(data['vdisp'])), max(np.log10(data['vdisp'])), bin_num1)
delta1 = bins1[1] - bins1[0]
idx1 = np.digitize(data['vdisp'], bin_num1, right = True)

running_med1 = [np.median(np.log10(prim_data['stellar_mass'])[idx1 == k]) for k in range(bin_num1)]

ax13.scatter(bins1 - delta1 / 2, running_med1, color = 'magenta')
```

However, I got the error

```
idx1 = np.digitize(data['vdisp'], bin_num1, right = True)
File '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py', line 4799, in digitize
mono = _monotonicity(bins)
ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array
```

How can I solve this problem??

I've already tried data['vdisp'].all() or .any()

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are the values in the data strings?

Comment: The error occurs when it is testing `bins` (docs says it must be 1d array and monotonic).  You gave it a scalar, 5, not an array.  Did you intend to use `bins1`?